# for looping and appending into list

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
list = []

def lecture(x):
    for x in range(1,x):
        print 'lecture', x
```

so I have this code that gives the result of

```
lecture 1  
lecture 2
```

for an input of `lecture(3)`. Now, when I change the code to

```
list = []

def lecture(x):
    for x in range(1,x):
        y = 'lecture', x
            print y
```

i get an output of

```
('lecture', 1)  
('lecture', 2)
```

Ultimately I would like to know why this is the case as I am trying to find a way of appending the first results, the:

```
lecture 1
lecture 2
```

into a list but I can't as I get a list with the lecture number separated from its number by a comma etc.

Comment: Because `y` is a tuple, and that's what tuples look like when you print them. Try explicit string formatting with `str.format`, or using the print function for greater control with `from __future__ import print_function` (or moving to Python 3.x, which you should do anyway).

Comment: is there a good reason why my university department is recommending us not to start with 3.x ?

Comment: What does the `list` variable have to do with this? You're not using it in the code.

Comment: Python 2.7 has more support for external libraries but it's considered "legacy".
Python 3.5 is the present and the future of the language, so the choice is yours!
From: http://learntocodewith.me/programming/python/python-2-vs-python-3/

Comment: What does your title have to do with the question? Where are you "appending into a list"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting that strange notation because `'lecture', x` is a [tuple](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm). A datatype which acts like a list, but a non-flexible list. You can't change them that easily. You have to use the +-operator instead of a comma to put those two values into one variable.

And putting values in a list is done with the `append` function.

```
list = []

def lecture(x):
    for x in range(1,x):
        y = 'lecture' + str(x)
        list.append(y);
lecture(5)
```

Also note:
`y = 'lecture' + str(x)`
the `str(x)` is to make sure the different datatypes (int and string) don't conflict. Because String + Int ain't possible.

- 5 (Int) + 5 (Int) is 10.
- 5 (String) + 5 (String) is 55.
- But 5 (String) + 5 (Int) is an error.

Answer (score 0):

Swap `y = 'lecture', x` with:

```
y = 'lecture ' + str(x)
```

This will append the variable `x` to `'lecture'` and set it in variable `y`

Comment: `str(x)` instead of `x`

Answer (score 0):

With the expression `y = 'lecture', x`, you are creating a tuple. Create an empty list instead, and append values to it with the for loop:

```
def lecture(x):
    lecture_list=[]
    for item in range(1,x+1):
        y='lecture '+str(item)
        lecture_list.append(y)
    return lecture_list
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way:

```
class Lectures(object):
  def __init__(self, x):
      self.x = x
  def __iter__(self):
      for i in range(1, self.x):
          yield "lecture" + i
```

Here an iterable class Lectures is made.

First you need to initialize it, passing x as an attribute:

```
lectures = Lectures(x)
```

Then you can use it as an iterable:

```
list_of_lectures = list(lectures)
```

or

```
for lecture in lectures:
    do_something
```